# rake cucumber and cucumber --tag @tagname give different results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, fixtures

If I use `rake cucumber` the fixtures are not loaded and my tests fail. If I use `cucumber --tag @tagname` to run a scenario it loads fixtures, factories, and everything passes.

The bottom of my `/features/support/env.rb` looks like this:

```
Cucumber::Rails::World.use_transactional_fixtures = true
Fixtures.reset_cache  
fixtures_folder = File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'spec', 'fixtures')
fixtures = Dir[File.join(fixtures_folder, '*.yml')].map {|f| File.basename(f, '.yml') }
Fixtures.create_fixtures(fixtures_folder, fixtures)

if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
  begin
    require 'database_cleaner'
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  rescue LoadError => ignore_if_database_cleaner_not_present
  end
end
```

Everything else is fairly standard Rails 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change this line:

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation, {:except => %w[degrees states_provinces contribution_types manuscript_types statuses countries roles user_templates]}
```

I needed all of those tables loaded for the tests to pass but DatabaseCleaner was truncating them after each scenario.